# Windows 10: 0x8007002C - 0x2000D failed update from Windows 7 to Windows 10

Tags: windows-10-upgrade

While trying to upgrade from Windows 7 (windows 7 home premium) to Windows 10 
during the copying files installation has been suddenly interrupted and system rebooted back to Windows 7 & i got the following message " SAFE_OS phase with an 
error during MIGRATE_DATA operation "

[image]

Please Help, any ideas how to fix error are appreciated

Comment: Have you tried it using .ISO ?

Comment: Yes. Installation package received from windows update was useless because of " boot.win" mistake. So using install.esd and esd-decrypter-wimlib-4 - i succesfully received my .ISO installation file. Click to Setup.exe and installation process was in progress... but it has been lasting for 20 min and met such a disappointment finally.

Comment: [Contact Microsoft Support](https://partner.support.services.microsoft.com/en-us/contact/menu/software/windows/setup/)

Comment: [See this answer](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_install/0x8007002c-0x4001c-error-while-installing-windows/cc435d09-27d4-42f8-a447-af830b340613?auth=1)

Comment: Moab, Thanks, Try to boot with only Microsoft Services and will try to install update in a safe mode. promise to return with a feedback

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1:**

*Step 1:* You can go to **PC settings.**
*Step 2:* Under Update and Recovery options, Select
"Refresh This PC".

> This refresh will delete your installed programs.
>   This might work.

After refresh it might ask for couple of Windows Update install them

**Solution 2:**  Run media creation tool and do a clean install of Windows 10

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi manubhargav, if I got it right "PC settings" options can be find inside Windows 8 or Windows 8.1 operation system. Although now I have Windows 7 and I apply "Control Panel" and use "Windows Update" option to start "Check for Updates"

Comment: what you need to do is goto a previous point of time before any faulty updates, so you can do a system restore in windows 7 and check for windows update later on

Answer (score 0):

Having taken into account all advices - i installed software for checking system registry - searching for spying software etc... , to my amazement scanning result has shown massive critical errors, which were succesfully fixed.

Having fixed registry errors- i noticed improving of whole PC productivity...

Rebooted under usual mode (not safe mode), initialized installation process i got following:
 1) succesfull passed through copying files 2) installed drivers and components 3) turned settings ... and finally met WINDOWS 10

Thanks to ALL. It works!